# Como mostrar/ocultar las opciones del menú segun grupo de django admin [DJANGO]

Tags: django

me gustaria saber como poder ocultar partes del menu segun grupo de django admin, vi que existe la opcion de {% if request.user.is_staff %} pero no se como para el grupo. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if perms.NOMBREDELAAPP.permisoquetieneelgrupo %}
```

Ejemplo si el grupo pudiese agregar un producto:

```
{% if perms.miapp.add_producto %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer lo siguiente:

```py
{% if 'Administrador' in request.user.groups.all %}
    <a href="#">Admin panel</a>
{% endif %}
```

Esto es todo.